# Reading json files from a directory throws exception with the provided path

Tags: java

I am trying to read bunch of json files and return them as List.
I am providing the path from the repository root as an argument, but i keep getting an "Unexpected exception thrown: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException".

Here is my code:

```
  private List<File> getFiles(String directoryPath) {
    File directory = new File(directoryPath);
    File[] files = directory.listFiles((dir, name) -> name.endsWith(".json"));
    if (files != null) {
      return Arrays.asList(files);
    } else {
      return Collections.emptyList();
    }
  }
```

The funny thing is if i provide a path from content root (src/main/resources/my_directory), it returns the files, but otherwise with path to repository root (my-app-1/src/main/resouces/my_directory) throws an exception.

Comment: You pass a relative path to a directory so it depends on a current working directory. If you are trying to start your program from IDE, your current working directory would be the root of your project. You can check it with `new File("").getAbsolutePath()`.

Comment: But what if the path that I am providing leads to a directory located in another module ?

Comment: You can use `..` in the path to move one directory up in the hierarchy, as in `”../another-module/src/main/resources/my_directory”`, or provide an absolute path.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should be able read anything that is place in the resource directory using the classloader as it will be available in the classpath. Please have a look at the code below, this should work for your case as well:

```
public class ClassToReadJsons {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new ClassToReadJsons().getFiles(ClassToReadJsons.class.getClassLoader().getResource("my_directory").getPath()).forEach(file -> System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath()));
  }
  private List<File> getFiles(String directoryPath) {
    File directory = new File(directoryPath);
    File[] files = directory.listFiles((dir, name) -> name.endsWith(".json"));
    if (files != null) {
      return Arrays.asList(files);
    } else {
      return Collections.emptyList();
    }
  }
}
```